# Accessing newly signed third party DLL gives error

Tags: .net, dll, .net-assembly, strongname

I have a signed application that uses third party DLLs. These DLLs were not signed. - So far no problem for the first step: I just signed them (getting *.il with ildasm.exe, ajust publickeytoken in the *.il 's because they have interdependencies, and made the *.dll's with ilasm.exe)

The project now compiles fine and also starts up.

But when in my code, a class constructor of the 3rd-party-DLL is called (or something else? - was just the first thing I did), I get the error *"Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their InternalsVisibleTo declarations"*

It seems there won't be a problem if you have the source of the DLL and can ajust in AssemblyInfo.cs by setting

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.Domain.Tests, PublicKey=..."]
```

**But:** As mentioned above I have a third-party DLL I **don't** have the source. So no way to solve the problem like this.

Any suggestions to get this running?

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same issue.

**Why it happens**

- The 3rd-party assembly is declared with `InternalsVisibleTo` to make it "friend" to other assemblies, e.g. `InternalsVisibleTo("OtherAssembly")`
- .NET requires that strong-name assembly can only be "friend" to other strong-name assemblies, in which case the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute must specify the public keys of those other assemblies, e.g. `InternalsVisibleTo("OtherAssembly, PublicKey=[key]")`
- At runtime, the CLR sees that `InternalsVisibleTo` is not properly declared for the assembly in question, so it throws the exception.

**How to fix**

If the "friend" assemblies aren't needed for the program execution (e.g. it's a Test assembly, which isn't deployed in production), follow these steps:

- Disassemble the assembly in question: `ildasm.exe ThirdParty.dll /OUTPUT=ThirdParty.il`
- Use a text editor to edit the IL file, remove any declaration of `InternalsVisibleTo`
- Assemble and sign the IL: `ilasm.exe ThirdParty.il /DLL /OUTPUT=ThirdParty.modified.dll /KEY=key.snk`
- ***Note**: generate a key by: `sn.exe -k key.snk`*

If the "friend" assemblies are needed for the program execution, you have to sign all those friend assemblies. Then follow similar steps as above, except instead of removing `InternalsVisibleTo`, you have to amend each declaration with the correct public key.

Comment: To assemble and sign the IL use ilasm.exe rather than ildasm.exe which is used for disassembly.