# Strongly named Rally.RestApi

Tags: rally

In my C# project, all assemblies are signed with a strongly name. However, one of them has reference to Rally.RestApi.dll which itself is not signed with a strongly name. This cause compile error "Error 41 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Rally.RestApi' does not have a strong name".

The question is: How can I sign Rally Rest API so that it has strong name? It took me quite a lot of times to find a way to sign Rally.RestApi.dll but NO luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202623/17815

Answer (score 1):

By design in the .NET Framework this is not allowed.  I will submit a defect tracking this issue since it is good practice to do this anyway.