# How to tell visual studio not needing the third party assembly to be signed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly, signing, strongname

I have a website with one class library which have been strongly signed.

I'd need to use a third party .dll which hasn't been signed and I don't have access to its source code to sign it.

How would that be possible that I tell visual studio not needing the third party assembly to be signed?

It's giving me the below error:

Error   1   Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'ThirdPartyDll' does not have a strong name.

Many thanks,

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738008/accessing-newly-signed-third-party-dll-gives-error-strong-name-signed-assemblie

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use unsigned assembly from signed assembly and there is no way to do what you ask. But it is possible to sign assembly without source.

see [this](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2010/04/23/sign-a-.net-assembly-with-a-strong-name-without-recompiling.aspx) on haw to do it.