# CefSharp with Strong-Named binaries

Tags: c#, cefsharp, strongname

Everything works on machines where the .NET Framework registry key `AllowStrongNameBypass` is enabled.
However, we require that the `AllowStrongNameBypass` be disabled on our deployed environment.

We need to have `CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe` and its unmanaged dependencies Strong-Named (preferably WITHOUT building CefSharp ourselves).

As a test, we tried giving the assemblies Strong-Name keys ourselves by disassembling `CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe` using `ildasm.exe` and reassembling it using `ilasm.exe` and a key generated using `sn.exe`. Unfortunately, this failed with `MethodAccessException`.

Is there an available version of CefSharp where the assemblies are Strong-Named or a way around this issue?

Comment: I installed v51.0.0 from NuGet and ran `sn -T "[dll]"` and the dll's I checked, including `CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe`, had strong names. If your version does not maybe try looking into why `MethodAccessException` is occurring, I found this post about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738008/accessing-newly-signed-third-party-dll-gives-error

Comment: @dukedukes what I'm seeing on my v51.0.0 binaries is the command `sn.exe -Tp CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe` displays the public key (which I can see with `ildasm` as well). Although the command `sn.exe -vf CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe` return the following error: `Failed to verify assembly -- Strong name validation failed for assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe'.`

Comment: I tried `sn -vf CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe` just now and saw the same thing but only for 32-bit, 64-bit validated correctly. I tried both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of sn.exe. An option could be resigning the assembly with the `CefSharp.snk` key available in the CefSharp GitHub repo then repeat for each assembly that has this issue.

Comment: It seems the post build step for x86 built `CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe` binaries invokes `editbin.exe` with the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag. This flag seems to break strong name verification. Also @dukedukes is correct, using `sn.exe -R CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe [CefSharp key]` seems to make the strong name valid (according to `sn.exe -vf`).

@dukedukes you might as well write it up as an answer.

Comment: Good find. FYI i submitted an issue on CefSharp's GitHub page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CefSharp appears to have some invalid strong named assemblies. As @Fizz points out the post build step for `CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe` under the 32-bit platform is the cause of this.

Re-sign the problem assemblies with the CefSharp.snk key available in the CefSharp GitHub repo. You can re-sign them with the following command:

`sn.exe -R CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe [CefSharp key]`